# Обновление ListView в PagerAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-viewpager

Делаю парсинг `Json` в `ListView`. Использую вывод в табы через `PagerAdapter`.

Вот исходный код фрагмента:

```
public class FragmentOffshoreView extends Fragment {

private static final String url = "http://********";


private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

private VolleySingleton volleySingleton;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private RequestQueue requestQueue;
private ArrayList<Article> listArticle = new ArrayList<>();
private CustomListAdapter adapter;
private ListView listViewArticleFragment;

public FragmentOffshoreView(){

}

private String[] category = {"Новости", "Статьи", "Юрисдикции", "События в мире",
                            "Аналитика", "Интересное"};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    volleySingleton = VolleySingleton.getInstance();
    requestQueue = volleySingleton.getRequestQueue();
    sendJsonRequest();
}

private void sendJsonRequest() {
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            listArticle = parseJSONResponse(response);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private ArrayList<Article> parseJSONResponse(JSONObject response) {

    listArticle = new ArrayList<>();

    if(response == null || response.length() > 0){

    }
    try {
        JSONArray arrayArticle = response.getJSONArray("posts");
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayArticle.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject currentArticle = arrayArticle.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = currentArticle.getInt("id");
            String title = currentArticle.getString("title");
            String thumbnail = currentArticle.getString("thumbnail");
            String date = currentArticle.getString("date");
            String content = currentArticle.getString("content");
            JSONArray categoryArray = currentArticle.getJSONArray("categories");
            Article article = new Article();
            for (int j = 0; j < categoryArray.length(); j++) {
                JSONObject currentCategory = categoryArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String category = currentCategory.getString("title");
                article.setCategory(category);
            }




            article.setId(id);
            article.setTitle(title);
            article.setThumbnailUrl(thumbnail);
            article.setDate(date);
            article.setContent(content);

            listArticle.add(article);

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {

    }
    return listArticle;
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blog_with_tabs, container, false);


    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.name_fragment_offshore);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerBlogs);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter());

    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.slidingTabBlogs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return category.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return object == view;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return category[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
        container.addView(view);
        if(category[position] == "Новости" ) {
            listViewArticleFragment = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listArticleFragment);
            adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), listArticle);
            listViewArticleFragment.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View)object);
    }
}
}
```

Столкнулся вот с такой проблемой:
При запуске приложения не отображается список статей, только если пролистать все табы до конца, а потом вернутся назад на первый то появляется результат. Может какой то метод дополнительный нужно использовать? Или может у меня что то в коде не так(код может быть не корректным и будет подвержен критике, но я только учусь критику приму и проанализирую).

Comment: Расскажите подробнее что происходит, а то в коде все смешано в кучу. Вы хотите сделать табы при помощи ViewPager и один из табов это FragmentOffshoreView? Или вы хотите табы внутри FragmentOffshoreView?

Comment: @ander табы внутри FragmentOffshoreView. `String[] category` - массив названий табов.

Comment: Очевидно, причина в том, что при первом появлении списка данные, которые он должен отображать, еще не подготовлены.  Вам нужно позаботиться о том, чтобы эти данные были получены раньше, чем список появится на экране.

Answer (score 1):

а если попробовать устанавливать адаптер в onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)?

Comment: не помогло. Вообще список не отображается.